# Disable browser creating desktop notifications if site isn't open

Tags: firefox, browser, notifications

When using web versions of chat apps such as WhatsApp, Skype, or Telegram I allow them to send me desktop notifications, which they use for new messages. But it seems that this allows for those sites to then continue to send me push notifications even when I close them, using something called Service Workers. Meaning that every time after that when I open my browser with zero pages, I'll get a flood of messages that have been sent to me in the meantime.

I've only found ways to disallow them to use desktop notifications altogether. Which is not what I want, notifications are okay. But what I want is to only disallow the notifications if I'm not currently using them (have their site open).

I am currently using Firefox, but I would appreciate knowing if other browsers can control this as well.

Comment: What OS, or are you experiencing this on every OS?

Comment: @AFH Sorry i didn't think it would be relevant. It's Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know how relevant it is, but it stops blind alleys if checks are done on the same OS.

Comment: I've just tested WhatsApp Web with PaleMoon (a Firefox derivative) on Ubuntu 16.04.3. I sent a message and I got the notification and the message. I then stopped PaleMoon and sent another message. When I restarted PaleMoon I got the message, but no notifications. Isn't this the behaviour you want?